# Trigger on show event for bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This question has probably been answered already however I am trying to ask it as specific as possible.

Using the examples found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). Under the varying content based on trigger button.

I have a bootstrap modal that is opened with an `<a></a>` tag which needs to be given information from AngluarJS. The example uses Jquery to do some magic and pass the data in.

**BIG Edit** Lots of code appearing here because something is slightly wrong. I am thinking it is in when the scripts load.

On live demo please attempt to debug and find why the `var Index = button.data('Index')` comes out undefined. - **Fixed - case sensitive**

Final problem why is the jquery failing at

> VM155:8 Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).logic.UpdateNews is not a function

**Done it works, I freaking got it all!**

HTML:

```
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-News-Ticker-Plugin-with-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-News-Box/scripts/jquery.bootstrap.newsbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt logo-inverse pull-left"></span><b> General News</b></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="demo1" style="overflow-y: hidden; height: 280px;" ng-model="Idk">
                                <li style="" class="news-item text-left" ng-repeat="item in News.GeneralNews"><strong>{{item.DateValue | date: "MMM dd yyyy"}}</strong>{{item.Preview}}<a class="FakeClickable" data-target="#GeneralModal" data-toggle="modal" data-Index="{{item.Index}}">Read more...</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div ng-if="Width>768">
                                <div ng-include="'../pages/Modals/General/GENERAL_INLINE.html?Update=Yes'"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="GeneralModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:auto;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <div class="FixModalHeader">
                    <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="../Content/Images/Icons/favicon-32x32.png">
                    <span style="">{{NewsCast.HeaderTitle}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div data-ng-include="'../pages/Modals/General/GENERAL_MODAL.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("I was here!");
            $('#GeneralModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                var Index = button.data('Index') // Extract info from data-* attributes
                // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
                // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
                angular.element('#mycontroller').scope().logic.UpdateNews('General', Index);
                angular.element('#mycontroller').scope().$apply();
            })
        });
</script>
<script>
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
</script>
```

What happens inside the last ng-include:

```
<div class="html-format">
<div ng-bind-html="NewsCast.General.Body">

</div>
```

What I need answered:

- Can I have have the jquery function trigger and then change something in my AngularJs code? The way I have my modals set up is the text and stuff appearing on them is data-bound to Angular objects. If the jquery can change a value in my angular all my modals will work.
- Even more specific if the jquery can call a function from my angularjs code and pass in some arguments I'll really be set.
- I'll take suggestions on proper code edikit please

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understand correctly then you can use a service for this. Inject the service into both the controller with the jquery and the controller with the databound DOMs. Then if you store the data as well as functions to alter the data in the service you can alter it in both places and also bind it to the $scope of each.
2. You can use a service for this as described above.
3. I'm not an expert on Angular code etiquette, but you can do it this way.

[Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)
[Simpler example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp) Note: see creating custom service.

Comment: Right now I am using sample data that I have just input. The intent is to eventually have the news come in from a database. I just want to make sure sample data works.

Comment: I am running into a bigger problem though

Comment: My on show event for the modal doesn't trigger when I click my <a> tag and it opens.

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your original question with the relevant code snippets so we can identify the problem more easily.

Comment: Making one last update once it is posted please feel free to debug on live demo, go to recent news and click read more.